# Looping through json using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I have a complex JSON object from which I have to loop through it and render the data in the form. For that I have created a small service like this:

```
service.myApprovalResults = function(){
        var url = "../data/myapprovals.json";
        return $http.post(url).success(function(response) {
         $rootScope.names = response;
        });
    };
```

The following is my JSON file:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
                    "Approval": {
                        "Id":"111",        // Unique Id
                        "Api":"api/sometihgn/111"
                     },
                    "Ticket":{
                    "Id":"TKT1000011",
                    "API":"api/ticket/TKT1000011"
                    },
                    "TicketItem":{
                    "Id":"RITM1000011",
                    "API":"api/ticket_item/RITM1000011"
                    },
                    "ProcessStep":"",
                    "Description":"Need Approval For sdsadas",  // See Note Section
                    "VariablesSet":// See Note Section
                        [         // VariableSet details.
                            { 
                                "Question":"Joining Date",
                                "Name": "joining_date",
                                "Id":"13",
                                "Value": ["12:12:2014"],
                                "DisplayValue":[""],
                                "Reference":""
                            },
                            {
                                "Question":"Reporting Manager",
                                "Name": "reporting_manager",
                                "Id":"14",
                                "Value": ["samd"],
                                "DisplayValue":["/Sam Doni"],
                                "Reference":"/api/user"
                            },
                            {
                                "Question":"Department",
                                "Name": "department",
                                "Id":"15",
                                "Value": ["IT Security"],
                                "DisplayValue":[""],
                                "Reference":""
                            },

                            {
                                "Question":"Accessories Needed?",
                                "Name": "accessories",
                                "Id":"16",
                                "Value": ["laptop","mouse"],
                                "DisplayValue":[""],
                                "Reference":""
                            }
                        ],                             
                    "ApprovalFor": {   
                        "Name": "Sam Doni",
                        "UserName": "samd",
                        "Email":"samd@test.com",
                        "Api": "api/user/samd" // Api can be used to get more details
                     },
                    "Approver":{    // Optional
                        "Name": "sdsdsdsad",
                        "UserName": "sdsdsad",
                        "Email":"sadsads@dssdf.com",
                        "Api": "api/user/dssds" // Api can be used to get more details
                     },
                    "State": "Requested",
                    "Group": "",// Optional
                    "CreatedBy": {
                        "Name": "sadsdsddsa",
                        "UserName": "sdsd",
                        "Email": "sdsad@test.com",
                        "Api": "api/user/sadsadsa"
                    },
                    "CreatedOn": "2016-11-09T17:29:01Z",
                    "UpdatedOn": "2016-11-09T17:29:01Z",
                    "CommentsSet": [{
                            "Id": "10",
                            "TicketItem": "RITM1001011",
                            "Type": "approvalnote",
                            "Value": "User has issues related to access",
                            "CreatedOn": "2016-11-09T17:29:01Z",
                            "CreatedBy": {
                                "Name": "sdsdsadsadd",
                                "UserName": "dsdsad",
                                "Email":"sdsad@test.com",
                                "Api": "api/user/ssddsad"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "Id": "11",
                            "TicketItem": "RITM1001011",
                            "Type": "approvalnote",
                            "Value": "Issue is solved",
                            "CreatedOn": "2016-11-08T17:29:01Z",
                            "CreatedBy": {
                                "Name": "dsadsdsad
                                "UserName": "sdsadas",
                                "Email":"dsads@test.com",
                                "Api": "api/user/sadsadsadsa"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                 },
                {
                    "Approval": {
                        "Id":"112",     
                        "Api":"api/approval/112"
                     },
                    "Ticket":{
                    "Id":"TKT1000013",
                    "API":"api/ticket/TKT1000013"
                    },
                    "TicketItem":{
                    "Id":"RITM1000021",
                    "API":"api/ticket_item/RITM1000021"
                    },
                    "ProcessStep":"",
                    "Description":"Add user to Helpnow Group",// See Note Section
                    "VariablesSet":// See Note Section
                        [
                            { 
                                "Question":"Location Service Needed",
                                "Name": "location",
                                "Id":"16",
                                "Value": ["11"],
                                "Reference":"/api/location";
                            },
                            {
                                "Question":"What is the issue",
                                "Name": "service_needed",
                                "Id":"18",
                                "Value": ["aloha"]
                                "DisplayValue":[""],
                                "Reference":""
                            }
                        ],                     
                    "ApprovalFor": {   
                        "Name": "dsfdsfdsf",
                        "UserName": "dfdsf
                        "Email":"dfdsfds@gmail.com",
                        "Api": "api/user/rsds// Api can be used to get more details
                     },
                    "Approver":"",
                    "State": "Requested",
                    "Group": {
                             "Name": "FIN Group",
                             "Id":"10"
                            "Api": "api/group/10"// Unique Group ID in SAP
                        }

             }
     ]
}
```

Using this JSON I need to loop through and show the JSON data in the form. and I have added the following code below:

```
<ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in names">
            {{ x.result.Approval.Id }}, {{ x.result.Ticket.Id }}, {{x.result.TicketItem.Id}}, {{x.result.Description}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Done the above things but I am not able to see the data in the form.

I have checked the chrome developer tools and the JSON is loading properly.
Can anybody suggest me?

Comment: ng-repeat only works with Array, not with Object.

Comment: double check that that JSON response is valid as well

Comment: @Ved - `ng-repeat` can work with objects as well.

Comment: @31piy ng-repeat with object works like this way. `(key,val) in object`. So technically it works with Array only.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrongly iterating through your data. I believe you want to display the details in your array.

You need to change `x in names` to `x in names.result`. And then, change your expressions to use `x` directly like this:

```
{{ x.Approval.Id }}, {{ x.Ticket.Id }}, {{x.TicketItem.Id}}, {{x.Description}}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, check if have assigned `$rootScope.names` as an empty array while declaratiion. If that is the case try to directly declare and assign it only in the service if possible (to avoid further complication of the data structure).

According to your JSON structure your code should be like:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="x in names.result">
  {{ x.Approval.Id }}, {{ x.Ticket.Id }}, {{x.TicketItem.Id}}, {{x.Description}}
 </li>
</ul>
```

Further, to avoid this level of complexity, try to restructure your JSON and response storage from the next time :)

Comment: Sriram, i have assigned to an empty array before the response comes into it and when i open the DOM simply it gives me this tag <!-- ngRepeat: x in names.result -->

Comment: Try modifying `names.result` to `$root.names.result.`

If that doesn't work just try logging:`$rootScope.names.result[0].Approval.Id` so as to verify whether the parsing that I suggested is correct.

Comment: Tried this $rootScope.names.result[0].Approval.Id but got this Uncaught ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: Where did you log it? And did you inject `$rootScope` into the function?

Comment: Added this service ...  service.myApprovalResults = function(){
  var url = "../data/myapprovals.json";
  return $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
  var names = [];
         $root.names = response;
   console.log($root.names.result);
   console.log($rootScope.names.result[0].Approval.Id);
        });

Comment: You cannot access the `$rootScope` without injecting this 'service' into your controller, factory or service. Add `$rootScope` to `service.myApprovalResults = function($rootScope)`.  And I don't think you can use `$root.names`, it must be `$rootScope.names`.

Comment: I have already created a service and named it as myservice and injected in the controller as       var myApprovalController = function ($scope,$rootScope, mainService) {
   $scope.myapproval = [];
      console.log($rootScope.names.result[0].Approval.Id);
}

app.controller('myApprovalController', ['$scope','$rootScope', 'mainService']);

Comment: If `mainService` is the name of your service, shouldn't you be calling the service's method i.e.`mainService.myApprovalResults`to assign values into the `$rootScope` before trying to access or log them now?

Comment: In mainService i have so many services but here i am using service as an array to store all the myApprovalResults so i am referring the service instead of mainService.

Comment: Can you post the entire code of your current action? The view and the controller if you don't use the service.